# how to install opencv2.4 for windows7?

Tags: opencv, installation

i'm trying to install Opencv2.4 for windows7 using guidelines of http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide and i could complete up to the debug and release section. but as the last step they said we should change system path of the computer and i don't know how to change that. (yes i changed  environment variables's path for debug folder, but i don't know how to change that for Release folder .Because there is only one path variable )

Comment: The OpenCV site moved to opencv.org, with docs at docs.opencv.org . WillowGarage site is deprecated

Comment: finally i did all the steps as the <http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide> and i tried to run a program(when i using opencv2.1 ;that program could run without errors ), but there were  several errors occurred during that time.i think there is some more things should do for the installing process.(because for opencv2.1 i add "Additional Dependencies" for Configuration Properties > Linker > Input and add include files, library files and source files to- Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories and for opencv2.4 i didn't do those kind of stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find good tutorial regarding installing Opencv. i think that will useful to you as well. This is the [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZvjTTK9zTw&feature=related)

Answer (score 0):

Like they say in the page you linked

"[Windows] If you built OpenCV as dynamic libraries (DLLs), you may want to add \bin to the system path (**My Computer--[Right button click]-->Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables->Path**) to let Windows find "opencv_core240.dll" etc.) "

But in Visual Studio 2010 you can change ralease (and any other configuration's) environment variables trough Project ->  properties and then change configuration to "Release" from the selection list top left corner.

Comment: but when i change path for "Debug" folder, i cannot change path for "Release" folder. because when i reedit path por Relese folder there is no any path for Debug folder. because there is only one path variable there?
is that possible for visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

The system PATH variable decides the path from which the DLLs need to be picked up( in this case). Add both the release and debug paths to the variable. All debug libraries of OpenCV end with a `d` [example: `opencv_calib3d242d.dll`] as opposed to the release libs [`opencv_calib3d242.dll`]. Hence there will never be a collision between libraries - it will be solely dependent on what you link with.

Answer (score 0):

a simple command, to add new paths to the windows "path", a rough exampel might look like this:
`"set PATH=%PATH%;%OPENCV_DIR%\bin"` **or**

`"set PATH=%PATH%;%OPENCV_DIR%\debug"`
(or whatever the path to the debug folder might be)

type `"Echo %path%"` to see current windows Path at a command prompt